# CSS, change stylesheet if mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'am having trouble changing CSS file paths if the end user is accessing my site via a PC or mobile device, below is my CSS, I thought that it would redirect the user if using any handheld device:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css"  href="/css/mobile.css"   media="handheld" />
```

Please can someone let me know if this is the correct way or should I be using javascript to manipulate my file path>

Comment: media queries! :) http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html

Answer (score 3):

Dont make life too hard on yourself going that route of detecting a browser and device type..

Go with Media Queries..

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

All devices are now all well known but regardless the resolution will determine the css style you offer the client..

A Lot more can be found here : [MediaQueries](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html)

I would suggest MAYBE bootstrap3 framework // foundation etc there are a lot to choose from but these are the top two which come with built in definitions and a good framework to write css for each!

What you want to focus on is the grid system..

such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) They work of a col-size-n grid of 12 colums, responsive.

A Lot more documentation can be found there and it opens a world of other questions!

:)

Comment: @soc86 no problem ! I always appreciate a developer who is concerned about mobile enviornments!

Comment: Just be careful with Bootstrap, alot of overhead in some cases.

Comment: @Greg agreed, which is why i stressed 'maybe' but bootstrap does remove a lot of the grunt work with media queries

Comment: actually i've got a client that specifically wants a form to appear differently on mobile, even though the media queries work, because phone resolutions are now quite high pixel count now, so they won't necessarily change at the same width as it does on laptop or computer monitors

Comment: Wouldn't the problem with this be that if a mobile screen has more than 480 pixels in width, then the css would still render without the settings passed in the media condition?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the proper way would be **Media Queries**.

As mentioned by another individual on your question, if your truly trying to utilize Javascript:

```
function Resize() {
     width = window.innerWidth;
     height = window.innerHeight;

     if(width < 1200 && height < 600) {
          // Modify particular Stylesheet elements.
     }
}
```

Obviously you can do measurement / comparison:

- Browser Inner Width / Height
- User Agent

Those are two examples, but really Media Queries would be ideal and proper.  Won't go into detail on those Media Queries, since someone went into more detail.

Comment: I like this as it does offer an "easier" approach than introducing a new framework o rewriting all your css